# Переключение между окнами QT

Tags: c++, qt

Сегодня я столкнулся с проблемой, я не могу открыть главное окно из третьего окна, то есть я открываю второе, затем третье, но из третьего не могу вернуться к первому.

Я соединяю два окна и могу между ними переключаться

в mWindow.h я подключаю заголовочный файл второго окна:

```
//второе окно:
#include "profile.h"

private:

    Profile *profile;
```

в конструкторе mWindow.cpp я создаю новый объект класса Profile и соединяю его:

```
profile = new Profile();
connect (profile, &Profile::ToMainWindow, this, &MainWindow::show);
```

И по нажатию на кнопку:

```
    this->close();
    profile->show();
```

в profile.h у меня есть сигнал ToMainWindow:

```
signals:
    void ToMainWindow();
```

в Profile.cpp по нажатию на кнопку:

```
    emit ToMainWindow();
    this->close();
```

Таким же образом я могу переключиться из второго окна в третье и наоборот (из третьего во второе).
Но как соединить сигнал третьего окна с открытием первого окна, а не второго?

Comment: Показываете ли вы окна с помощью ` .exec()` или ` .show()`? Эти окна наследники  QDialog? Меняли ли вы флаги окон (`setWindowFlags`)? Наконец, каким кодом вы пытаетесь вернуться в первое окно, и что при этом происходит?

Comment: @Chorkov Я внёс корректировки и показал каким способом я переключаюсь между окнами

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как переключаться между окнами туда обратно?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1139231/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%82%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be)

Comment: Хватит спамить - внимательно прочитайте и посмотрите мой ответ, а также документацию.

Comment: @AlexanderChernin, прошу понять и простить). Кстати, данный вопрос был закрыт по этому я открыл новый.