# Переключение между окнами (QT)

Tags: c++, qt

Я столкнулся с проблемой, я не могу открыть главное окно из третьего окна, то есть я открываю второе, затем третье, но из третьего не могу вернуться к первому.

Я соединяю два окна и могу между ними переключаться

в mWindow.h я подключаю заголовочный файл второго окна:

```
//второе окно:
#include "profile.h"

private:

    Profile *profile;
```

в конструкторе mWindow.cpp я создаю новый объект класса Profile и соединяю его:

```
profile = new Profile();
connect (profile, &Profile::ToMainWindow, this, &MainWindow::show);
```

И по нажатию на кнопку:

```
this->close();
profile->show();
```

в profile.h у меня есть сигнал ToMainWindow:

```
signals:
    void ToMainWindow();
```

в Profile.cpp по нажатию на кнопку:

```
emit ToMainWindow();
this->close();
```

Таким же образом я могу переключиться из второго окна в третье и наоборот (из третьего во второе). Но как соединить сигнал третьего окна с открытием первого окна, а не второго?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Переключение между окнами QT](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1144093/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-qt)

Comment: тот переоткрыть или оставить этот... ну модераторы решат

Comment: Делал бы в одном окне на через QStatckedWidget - не было б проблем.

Comment: @eri Программа большая не хотелось бы всё в один файл помещать

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как переключаться между окнами туда обратно?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1139231/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%82%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be)

Comment: @AlexanderChernin, я правильно понял, что с помощью сигналов в main можно переключаться из любого окна в какое захочешь?

Comment: При помощи сигналов-слотов можно сделать очень многое, включая ваши проблемы. Читайте документацию и пробуйте

Comment: @SuperMyke так фреймы раскидаешь по файлам без проблем